# Django Internationalization - Language not change

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have already searched on many post but none could solve my problem.

My settings.py :

```
from os import path
PROJECT_ROOT = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
LOCALE_PATHS = (path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '/conf/locale/'),)

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-fr'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
gettext = lambda x: x
LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('en', gettext('English')),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR = (
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
)
```

urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import *
urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    ...
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
)
```

template.html (reduced version) :

```
<div id="header">
    ...
    {% include 'i18n.html' %}
</div>
```

i18n.html :

```
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Une ligne de test" %}
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }} />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I know this code has already appeared in many other posts but none solutions helped me.
My problem is that when i submit the form, the page reloads but the dropdown return on "French".

Furthermore, when i try an obsolete translation in /locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po for "Une ligne de test", i don't have the translate so I believe it doesn't access but I don't know why

Someone would have something to offer me please ?

---

### |     UPDATE     |

When I run `python manage.py runserver` the translation don't work but I have in the terminal `"POST /i18n/setlang/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` so I think that this calls for the function set_language() but I really don't understand why the language don't change and why an obsolete translation doesn't display with the initial language.

And when I try `LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"`, the dropdown take the value English but all the page stay in French.

For the information, I use Django 1.4.11 but I don't think that's my problem.

---

### |     UPDATE     |

I tried too with this template, with only one choice to try change the language but the result is always the same.

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value "{{ request.get_full_path|slice:'3:' }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="English" />
</form>
```

What does it missing ?

Comment: Add the method of setting language

Comment: What middleware do you use to save the user's choice? Is SessionMiddleware enabled in your  settings for example? And second, have you added i18n to your templates context processors in settings?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot write that. I had in settings.py TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR = ("django.core.context_processors.i18n",) and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",)

Comment: The method of setting language ? Do you mean replace "/i18n/setlang/" ?